# Resize picture size in tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, image-resizing

I wanted to know if there is a method to resize an image that has been loaded into Tkinter label widget. I have been trying to make a dice simulator using Tkinter which will display the image of dice showing random numbers. The problem is that these images do not have similar size. Here is the starting part of the program:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from random import choice

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Dice Simulator')
root.geometry('400x400')
root.resizable(0, 0)

dice = ['die1.jpg', 'die2.jpg', 'die3.jpg', 'die4.jpg', 'die5.jpg', 'die6.jpg']
DiceImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(choice(dice)))

ImageLabel = tk.Label(root, image=DiceImage)
ImageLabel.image = DiceImage
ImageLabel.pack(expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Can we resize the images to 400x400 and display all of them?

Comment: Better resize the source image files to the desired size so that they can be used directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a `resize(x,y)` method for `open` to resize images to the given width(x) and height(y).

```
dice = ['die1.jpg', 'die2.jpg', 'die3.jpg', 'die4.jpg', 'die5.jpg', 'die6.jpg']
resized_opened_img = [Image.open(x).resize((400,400),Image.ANTIALIAS) for x in dice]

DiceImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(choice(resized_opened_img))
```

Here it resizes the image to a 400x400 square image and appends these objects to a list and later you randomly choose one from it using `choice`. [Read more about `resize` here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize)

You can also get rid of `ImageLabel.image = DiceImage` as long as this is outside a function.

Comment: Could you please explain what does the `Image.ANTIALIAS` do?

Comment: @SiddheshAgarwal Sure, its more image basics, Anti aliasing smooths the rough edges of the images if any, while resizing.